# Change acitivity background color and possibly animate it

Tags: android, android-activity

I've found this code here but I can't manage to make it work in my app

```
public void setActivityBackground(int color) {
    View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    v.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

I'm trying to implement it in a switch listener (onCheckedChanged) and I'm calling it inside the listener in my fragment as

`((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActivityBackground(Color.CYAN);`

But nothing happens. What could be wrong? There's a way I can animated that change?

Comment: Make sure your fragment View is transparent, or Activity background will be covered by the Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by 'possibly animate it'. I assume you want to animate the changes of background color. Right? This solution is not entirely correct but it might help you to get an idea how to do it.

1) Fragment Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.ola.com.example.FragmentExample">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) Fragment Class

```
public class FragmentExample extends Fragment {

private OnCheckedChangeListener mListener;
private Switch switchFragment;

public FragmentExample() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_example, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    switchFragment = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.switchFragment);
    switchFragment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(null != mListener)
                mListener.onCheckChange(b);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnCheckedChangeListener) {
        mListener = (OnCheckedChangeListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnCheckedChangeListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onCheckChange(boolean b);
}
}
```

3) Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="app.ola.com.example.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

4)Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentExample.OnCheckedChangeListener{

private RelativeLayout rootView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rootView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.mainContent, new FragmentExample()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onCheckChange(boolean isChecked) {
    //animate
    if(isChecked){
        ObjectAnimator.ofObject(rootView, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255), Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 0))
                .setDuration(300)
                .start();
    }
    else{
        ObjectAnimator.ofObject(rootView, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 0), Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255))
                .setDuration(300)
                .start();
    }
}
}
```

5) Result

[image]

**Note**

1) Instead of calling `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActivityBackground(Color.CYAN)`, you can create an Interface in fragment class and implement the interface in Activity class. This is the proper way how you communicate between fragment-activity. You can refer to Android Developers documentation for brief explanation: [Communication with other fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

2) I use ObjectAnimator to animate the changes of background color from white to black with 78% of opacity. 'rootView' is the parent view of the layout activity. You can refer to activity layout.

Comment: Perfect man! Tested it right now and it's working as I wished. Thanks for the tips too!

Comment: Glad it helped. Just a side note, as @Suhyeon Lee said; if you fragment background view is not transparent, you cannot see the animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the method "setActivityBackground(int color)" as static  in a public class ，and call it in the fragmengt as “class.setActivityBackground(Color.CYAN)”，try it;

Comment: If there might be multiple activity instances that should be maintained asynchronously, this code will change the whole instances.

Comment: yes , and then I have no other ways except do it in XML file ,